# Chef provisioning on vcenter

Tags: chef-infra

I want to create the vm's on the vcenter using a template with chef.

1)I created the VM in vcenter
2)created a template for the VM.
3)I need to write a cookbook to automatically create the vm in vcenter based on the template i give. I should not use knife for it . I have to use drivers for it.

I found the link [chef-vspshere-driver](https://github.com/CenturyLinkCloud/chef-provisioning-vsphere), but its not so clear, can someone explain how to install it and how to use it from scratch

Comment: template_name: 'vmfs/volumes/Datastore_Esx2/Templatefolder/TemplateName.vmdk',

Comment: is that the correct way to give path?

Answer (score 0):

Chef isn't great at provisioning machines, especially without knife. Kitchen will do it, but it isn't meant for production use (although it gets used that way).

You might be better served by looking at Terraform to provision the machines, then configure with knife. Although, I'm here in the first place looking for answers on a terraform+chef question, so your mileage may vary.